# How to retrieve the value passed in POST method?

Tags: html, http-post

I would like to retrieve the value from POST method.
I know it’s possible to retrieve the GET method value - from query string.
So how is it possible for POST method?

Thanks,
Praveen jayapal

Comment: Which language/framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Going by the tags you have used, i assume you want to access POST data with javascript.

If so, **it is not possible** because the posted data are posted to the server not the client.. and the server returns a page without those..

If you use a server side language like php/asp/ruby/etc..etc.. (*do not flame me for the choices..*) then you can find creative ways to return the data back to the client and accessible from javascript ..